# Start pty asking for login credentials

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu, fork, pty

I've been working on a program in c++ that fork a pty. Everything goes well except for one thing: when the root run the program, the pty logs-in as the root user. In the same way, if a user 'x' runs the program, the new pty logs in as 'x' user.
How can it start a pty asking for the user credentias and login in? i know that ssh or pty1(ctr + alt + 1) does.

EDIT: Here is like i fork the pty
http://pastebin.com/3vLQynz2

Comment: How are you forking? You probably want to run `login` in the new process, not just the current user's default shell.

Comment: If the program run "login" command in the new process therefore can run "logout" and the user can run commands as root user. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be allowed to run something as a different user, you have to have to right to change to uid (man setuid). Normally you can only do this as user 'root'.

Therefore if you want to implement something like this either your program has to run as suid root or you have to use some other executeable that is suid root. For example you could ask the user which user it wants to be. Then run `/bin/su` to ask the user for his password.

BTW: the mentioned binary `/bin/login` will only work if you already run as user 'root'.

Comment: Hell man, "suid" can be the solution of all my problems. I will try now!